# State is not being updated in useCallback

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, event-listener

FINAL EDIT: I solved it, check my answer below

EDIT: So, the problem boils down to this. How can i change the value of a state from inside an eventListener? I have tried the things below, as well as the advice of the people below.
I can change it no problem from outside of an event listener but for this usecase it is quite important that it changes through an event

I have a boolean state variable whose job is to re-render an element.

In the use effect hook it works as expected, whenever one of the deps changes, it flips and re-renders the component.

The thing is, i need it to be fired with an event listener and it just does not.

`<EDIT>`: Sorry for the confusion, i am still learning.
I changed the code a bit.

```
const transition = () => {
    console.log("running callback");
    const content = document.getElementById("content");
    const greeting = document.querySelector(".fadeInAndOut");
    greeting?.addEventListener(
      "animationend",
      () => {
        console.log("event fired");
        greeting?.classList.remove("fadeInAndOut");
        greeting?.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0");
        content?.classList.add("fadeIn");
        console.log(`1 ${reset}`);
        setReset(!reset);
        console.log(`2 ${reset}`);
        cleanUp();
        greeting?.removeEventListener("animationend", () => {
          console.log("removed2");
        });
      },
      { once: true }
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    transition();
  }, []);
```

This is the effect that people have been asking to see. It flips the reset value when needed but the flipping in the event listener will not work even now

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setReset(!reset);
  }, [page, lang]);
```

`</EDIT>`

Here is the code:

```
  const transition = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("running callback");
    const content = document.getElementById("content");
    const greeting = document.querySelector(".fadeInAndOut");
    greeting?.addEventListener(
      "animationend",
      () => {
        console.log("event fired");
        greeting?.classList.remove("fadeInAndOut");
        greeting?.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0");
        content?.classList.add("fadeIn");
        console.log(`1 ${reset}`);
        setReset(!reset);
        console.log(`2 ${reset}`);
        cleanUp();
      },
      { once: true }
    );
  }, []);
```

When i console log it in the useEffect case, i get true,false,true etc...
console.log from the useCallback always returns the same value

I need this to only happen on first page load, hence the useCallback with no deps.

EDIT: changing the use callback to include "reset" in the deps does not solve the issue and also causes it to fire again. changing the setReset to

```
setReset(reset => !reset)
```

also does not change the state

Bonus question: I know react will fire the useCallback twice when developing but even though the event listener has the "once: true" option it gets added and therefore fired twice. Is something wrong with my declaration of it?

Comment: Use `setReset(oldReset => !oldReset);`. The `reset` value is a `const`, from the time your effect ran. You'd need to make `reset` a dependency of `useCallback`, but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: Do you expect ``console.log(`2 ${reset}`)`` to log a different value than ``console.log(`1 ${reset}`)``? [It never will!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1048572) Even when `setReset` does change the component state.

Comment: "*Bonus question: the event listener is fired twice. Is something wrong?*" - yes. Your effect (that you haven't shown) needs to return a cleanup function that removes the event listener. `once: true` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I see. Although, it triggers on page load so it's not like useEffect gets a chance to trigger twice. Would it be better practice to create a "hasFired" state that gets set to true when the function first fires and add a check for it in the begginning?

Comment: You haven't show the code with the `useEffect`, so I can't tell. No, do not use `hasFired`: the best practice is to do proper cleanup. If that is deemed unnecessary, just live with the event handler attached twice in dev mode, it's not harmful.

Comment: I am not on my laptop right now, but it simply fires the transition function and flips reset. It has two other states as deps so that it causes the component to re-render when they change. The usage of useCallback was to ensure the transition function only gets used on initial component load and not when the states that flip the reset changed. Although i could just use another useEffect... damn

Comment: Please post the `useEffect` code when you're back at your laptop, if you still want this question answered.

Comment: I added it to the original post, but i also figured it out!!! TL;DR i overcomplicated this.
Thank you for trying to help me and sorry if i wasted your time. You and the other people here did help me get a better grasp of what i am doing if it's worth anything.
Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i am not very smart. As the good people commented i never needed to use the useCallback hook. Now,i cannot get an event listener added to the element to fire a setState. So what i did was use this:

```
return (
    <>
      <Loading lang={lang} onAnimationEnd={handleAnimationEnd}></Loading>
      <Container style={{ opacity: 0 }} id="content" onAnimationEnd={cleanUp}>
...Rest of the html
```

and here are the functions

```
const cleanUp = () => {
    const target = document.getElementById("content");

    target?.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 1");
    target?.classList.remove("fadeIn");
    target?.removeEventListener("animationed", cleanUp);
  };

  const handleAnimationEnd = () => {
    const content = document.getElementById("content");
    const greeting = document.querySelector(".fadeInAndOut");

    console.log("event fired");
    greeting?.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
    greeting?.classList.remove("fadeInAndOut");
    content?.classList.add("fadeIn");
    setReset(!reset);
    greeting?.removeEventListener("animationend", handleAnimationEnd);
  };
```

Comment: "*an event listener added to the element cannot fire a setState*" - that's just not true.

Comment: `const target = document.getElementById("content");` - you should prefer `const { target } = event` where `event` is the parameter of the handler function

Comment: I doubt that `target.removeEventListener("animationed", …);` will work, when attaching the event handler via React.

Comment: changed the answer because you have a point... also i do no know if removing the event listeners this way works and i will have to further look into this since they are needed after the animations end. Lastly, if you could please provide more context for_ "const target = document.getElementById("content"); - you should prefer const { target } = event where event is the parameter of the handler function"_ as a proper answer along with any corrections i would be more than happy to give the checkmark to you for all the trouble you went through explaining this to me. Thank you <3

Comment: I meant that if you refer to the elements via [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), you may not need the ids (and care that they are globally unique). But not that important. I won't write an answer, I don't need checkmarks desparately :-)

Comment: Well, i just think you deserve it for the trouble. I get what you mean, i used e.target all the time in js but unless i use the "any" type for an event react makes me jump through hoops to do what i want. Idk if it really matters though.

Answer (score 0):

React's `useCallback` works based on `references`, meaning when `useCallback` returns a function, it memoize the definition of the function.

Your initial value of `reset` state, will be taken in function's definition, due to your dependency for `useCallback` being `[]`.

To support your case, just update it to,
`useCallback(() => { ... }, [reset]);`

Comment: It still gives the same output and now the callback is fired when the reset state changes which i want to avoid. What i want is for it to be called only once when the page first loads, do it's thing and then flip the reset so the component it is on re-renders. Is there a way to force a component re-render another way?

Comment: In that case, pass reset as the parameter, so you get the latest value always, without redefining the callback function. But it will duplicate your eventListeners.

For which you can use `removeEventListener` which is necessary to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: wouldn't the option {once:true} on the addEventListener solve that? Although when the callback is fired twice the event is then also fired twice so maybe not.

Comment: @GeorgeTheFool just don't memoize the event handler and everything should work fine. It's not even clear why you are memoizing it. Is this be re-rendered constantly in a tight loop (e.g. it's part of a long animation)?

Comment: When you use {once: true}, it executes/invokes any event listener once only, but with revise of memoization, it will add another eventListener (its definition). @GeorgeTheFool if you want it once only, reset wouldn't matter to you, but If it does, always good to follow best practices.

Comment: Would it be better to add a hasFired state var that the function sets to true and check for it in the begginning? I use the useCallback hook for things i want to do only once with useEffect or on specific conditions

Comment: If you want your useEffect to do things only once, it means there's no need for an updated value within the function. I think its best to move ahead with best practices.